# How to prevent a page break between paragraphs

Tags: macros, page-breaking, epigraphs

I would like to typeset something like a "quote plus attribution", e.g. at the beginning of a book chapter. It should look like this:

```
CHAPTER TITLE

       This  is an  introductory quote.
       It's stylistically questionable,
       but it's a fun LaTeX exercise.

                         -- said by  me

Now starts the main body text, which is not rele-
vant to this question. It just goes on and on and
on and on.
    It just looks like ordinary text.  You do not
have to keep reading.
```

For this purpose, I have an environment and a command, used like this:

```latex
\section{Chapter Title}

\begin{fooquote}
This is an introductory quote % etc. etc.
\quoteattribution{-- said by me}
\end{fooquote}
```

**Question:** How can I guarantee that there is no page break between the attribution and the body of the quote? I don't mind if there's a page break *within* the quote, but there shouldn't be one between the quote and the attribution.

I'm happy to change my entire setup if that's necessary. In my case, it's like this:

```
\newenvironment{fooquote}%
{ \bgroup
  \let\oldend=\end
  \def\end##1{\oldend{##1}\csname @afterindentfalse\endcsname
                          \csname @afterheading\endcsname}
  \begin{quote}%
  \itshape%
}{%
  \end{quote}
  \egroup
}
\newcommand{\quoteattrib}[1]{\normalfont\flushright#1}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Answering your question is difficult without knowing how your `foo` environment is defined. Note also that `\bar` is the name of an existing macro. Be careful not to overwrite it if you need it in your document.

Comment: @Jubobs: OK, done. My `fooquote` is a bit lengthy because I want to suppress indentation after the quote.

Comment: Use the `needspace` package, and on the last line of the quote, issue a `\needspace` for the anticipated gap+attribution. space  If it can't reserve it in advance, the page will break, with the end of the quote being bumped to the next page.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Hm, that sounded promising, but alas, no luck. No matter where I put `\needspace{3\baselineskip}`, the attribution ends up on the next page, all by itself.

Comment: When using the package, I've sometimes found the actual number of `\baselineskip`'s to be a non-precise measure.  Try increasing the number above 3, and experiment with how it works.

Comment: Only way to guarantee is to wrap it in a minipage. What you showing is actually an "epigraph" is it really this long? Try using the epigraph package.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Well, even if it's just, say, four lines long, I'd rather have the page break with two lines on either page than between the text and the attribution. And yes, sometimes it gets a lot longer, so a minipage isn't a good universal solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: (The "proper" solution would of course be to start each chapter on a new page... but let's pretend we don't want that.)

Comment: there's a very nice `epigraph` package (`texdoc epigraph`) which may suit your needs.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I had a look at this, and while the package looks very powerful (e.g. place epigraphs on "part" pages), it does exactly the opposite of the two things I care about: It does *not* unindent the subsequent text body, and it does *not* allow page breaks in the middle of the epigraph body (since it puts the entire thing in a minipage).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really it would be a lot easier to answer if there was a supplied example document, fragments are much harder to comment on but

```
\newenvironment{fooquote}%
{ \bgroup
  \let\oldend=\end
  \def\end##1{\oldend{##1}\csname @afterindentfalse\endcsname
                          \csname @afterheading\endcsname}
  \begin{quote}%
  \itshape%
}{%
  \end{quote}
  \egroup
}
\newcommand{\quoteattrib}[1]{\normalfont\flushright#1}
```

the `\bgroup` `\egroup` are not needed as the `fooquote` environment is already a group, also `{ \bgroup` introduces a space character.

The `\end` redefinition (which is rather dangerous really) appears to be too early it will affect the `\end` of any nested environment and in particular the `quote` environment. You just want to activate it after `fooquote` (I assume) so it should be right at the end of the end code of the definition.

`flushright` is intended to be an environment form, the declaration form being `\raggedleft` but if it's one line I'd probably just use `\hspace{\fill}`.
`\nopagebreak` ought to be enough to prevent page breaks at that point as long as there is flexibility elsewhere in the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fooquote}{%
  \begin{quote}%
  \itshape
}{%
  \end{quote}%
\par
\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse
\aftergroup\@afterheading
\ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand{\quoteattrib}[1]{\par\nopagebreak\normalfont\hspace*{\fill}#1\par}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{CCC}

\begin{fooquote}
red yellow blue
\quoteattrib{me}
\end{fooquote}

One two three. One two three. One two three. One two three.
One two three. One two three. One two three. One two three.
One two three. One two three. One two three. One two three.

One two three. One two three. One two three. One two three.
One two three. One two three. One two three. One two three.
One two three. One two three. One two three. One two three.

\end{document}
```